# Is there any way to add a listener to android.util.log?

Tags: android, logging, logcat, android-logcat

I want to do some extra stuff with my logs on debug build. Currently the app is using `android.util.Log` class (e.g. `Log.w(TAG, "msg");`directly, and they in turn appear in logcat.

Is there any way to capture stuff that is sent to logcat? Or is the only way to create a wrapper logger than executes my extra stuff and then calls to `util.Log`?

Answer (score 2):

- You can extend the class [`Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) yourself and add your own listeners ( interfaces and probably send local broadcasts and receive using Android `BroadcastReceiver`s) and respond to the information sent the way you want to.
- Or if you dont want to reinvent the wheel  you can explore some third party libraries like these [first](https://github.com/elvishew/xLog), [second](https://github.com/pedrovgs/Lynx)
  and [third](https://github.com/savio-zc/Android-Logger) and probably a lot more. Many support printing the Logs too and more!.